# How can I put counter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

In my leave management module I have a field , which displays count of employee took total leave and which are approved,
But unfortunately I can't get the count.

will anyone help me please???

Here is code of my view file

```
<div class="row">
<label class="col-md-6"><strong> Total Leave in this month </strong>/label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{$count}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code of controller file

```
public function handleLeave($id)
{
    $employeeName = User::all();
    $leaves = LeaveManagement::find($id);
    $count = LeaveManagement::where('status', '=', 'Approved')->count();
    return view('pages.leavelist', compact('leaves', 'id', 'count', 'employeeName'));
}
```

Comment: Can you `dd($count)` before `return view(...)` to see if `$count` variable has value? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: By the way, you can use `->where('status', 'Approved')` without `=`

Comment: By doing **dd($count);** it gives me **1**, I think it display 1 because it finds status approved in whole collection

Comment: But I want that, the particular employee's status approved

Comment: So, you have only one record with "Approved" status than. Do you?

Comment: Right Now yes,If i have 2 approve status record than it displays me 2,
can I share you an image?

Comment: You can, sure. But what's your problem than, if you get correct `count()` values?

Comment: https://ibb.co/hDY4my7 , See here Employee Adil took 1 leave and by default it status is pending, so when I click on detils it disaply me this https://ibb.co/kSxPbz0 , here count has to display 0, because Adil's any leave is not approved, But it displays 1

Comment: So, maybe try `->where('status', '<>', 'Approved')`? If you want do count unapproved leaves

Comment: Like this **$count = LeaveManagement::where($leaves)->where('status','<>' ,'Approved')->count();** ????

Comment: Without `where($leaves)`

Comment: that work man but that I dont want that, I have to put 0 over there this solution will check status of whole collection , I want that, That particular employee took leave and count of that approved leave

Comment: you are missing ->get()->count(); ?

Comment: my case I tested with Post::where('status','approved')->get()->count() and Post::where('status','approved')->count() both gives the same value. Can you try with ->get()->count() ?

Comment: ->get()->count() is not the correct way, then you load all models into an eloquent collection and counts them. ->count() uses SQL operations for the same which is way faster!

Comment: I am using mongoDb man